# Rename the Tuple Strings

Tags: c#

Whenever i print out the out of the Geocoding to a csv file. it names it item1 and item 2. so i want to change it to to latitude and longitude. the code is use of the conversion is:

```
static List<Tuple<string, string>> GeoCoding(string address)
{
    var json = new WebClient().DownloadString(baseUrlGC + address.Replace(" ", "+")
        + plusUrl);//concatenate URL with the input address and downloads the requested resource
    var jsonResult = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<GoogleGeoCodeResponse>(json);

    if (jsonResult.status == "ZERO_RESULTS")
        return new List<Tuple<string, string>> { new Tuple<string, string>("N/A", "N/A") };

    if (jsonResult.status != "OK")
        throw new Exception($"Request failed with {jsonResult.status}");

    return jsonResult.results
        .Select(result => result.geometry.location)
        .Select(loc => new Tuple<string, string>(loc.lat, loc.lng))
        .ToList();
}
```

Comment: Any reason you don't want to create a specific type for this? Or use an anonymous type? Or change how you're writing to the CSV file? (You haven't shown us that, or how this method is used in general.) Fundamentally, `Tuple` doesn't have anywhere to "put" names.

Comment: If you use a tuple, I believe you are stuck with the Item1/2 nomenclature. If its readonly data then consider a struct or records which should be lightweight enough. You will have control over its naming that way

Answer (score 2):

> i want to change it to to latitude and longitude

Use a type with those properties then.  For example:

```
public class Coordinates
{
    public string Latitude { get; set; }
    public string Longitude { get; set; }
}
```

(Or a `struct`, or a `record`, whatever is best for your needs.)

Change your method to return that type:

```
static List<Coordinates> GeoCoding(string address)
```

And return objects of that type:

```
.Select(loc => new Coordinates { Latitude = loc.lat, Longitude = loc.lng })
```

You can't re-name the properties on built-in types, but you can define your own types all you like.